# How to get a sales order ID and set it in a Custom Record in netsuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am very new to netsuite. I want to redirect a user from sales order to a custom record I created on button click, I want to get sales order ID and set it in the custom form where the user is being redirected by clicking a button the way fulfillment works in netsuite. I am using client script to redirect user when the button is clicked. Is there a way to pass the sale order id to the next form/Record?

Like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QghDv.png

I tried to use the saved search feature but I couldn't fully understand it. If indeed it can be done through saved search, it would be a great help if someone could guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Client Script you can use the `N/currentRecord` module to retrieve the ID of the record in context. It will allow you to retrieve a reference to the `CurrentRecord` object, which will have an `id` property.

See the Help page for `N/currentRecord` for details.